# EXIBIR UM DICIONÁRIO EM ORDEM ALFABÉTICA - PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x, classificação, dicionário

Tenho um dicionário que possui 2 chaves (nome, idade), dentro de cada existe uma lista de valores.

Preciso colocar os nomes em ordem alfabética e que as idades acompanhem os respectivos donos.

Essa foi a maneira que tentei:

```
lista = ['pedro', 'joao', 'marcelo']
dicionario = {'nome': ['pedro', 'joao', 'marcelo'], 'idade': [9, 4, 5]}

lista.sort()
print(lista)

dicionario['nome'].sort()

for x in range(len(dicionario['nome'])):
    print(dicionario['nome'][x], dicionario['idade'][x])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Genericamente falando, acho que a solução mais adequada seria criar uma classe que encapsulasse as duas informações, em dois atributos. Dessa forma elas estariam sempre juntas, e você não precisaria ter essa preocupação adicional de sempre estar vinculando as ações de uma lista em outra.

Porém, respondendo o que foi perguntado, pode-se utilizar a função [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) nas duas listas. Essa função é uma função embutida já no Python que agrega os elementos de diferentes iteráveis. Por exemplo:

Se a lista1 possui os elementos `[0,1,2,3,4]`, e a lista2 possui `['a','b','c','d','e']` então o retorno de `zip(lista1,lista2)` será `[(0,'a'),(1,'b')...]`

Aplicando no seu caso, temos:

```
#Mudei os nomes para uns mais simples (A,B,C)
dicionario = {'nome': ['Carolina', 'Ana', 'Beatriz'], 'idade': [1, 4, 5]}
print(dicionario)
# {'nome': ['Carolina', 'Ana', 'Beatriz'], 'idade': [1, 4, 5]}

#Atualizando a chave idade, baseado no que foi ordenado pela chave nome:
dicionario['idade'] = ([x for _, x in sorted(zip(dicionario['nome'], dicionario['idade']))])
print(dicionario)
#{'nome': ['Carolina', 'Ana', 'Beatriz'], 'idade': [4, 5, 1]}

#Por fim, atualizando a chave nome propriamente dita:
dicionario['nome'].sort()
print(dicionario)
#{'nome': ['Ana', 'Beatriz', 'Carolina'], 'idade': [4, 5, 1]}
```

Ou seja, em linhas gerais:

- Com o `zip` nós associamos as duas listas:  `zip(dicionario['nome'], dicionario['idade'])`
- Ordenamos o resultado com: `sorted(zip(...))`
- Com compreensão de listas, desempacotamos apenas o elemento de idade após a ordenação: `[x for _, x in listaDeTuplasOrdenadas]`

Para uma leitura mais aprofundada, leia [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6618543/10746978) (em inglês).

Comment: Cara, deu certinho...muito obg! Tava quebrando a cabeça faz um tempo já....vlw msm xD

Comment: @HenriqueMarvinSouzadaSilva De nada! Se a resposta lhe agradou, não esqueça de aceitá-la para ajudar futuras buscas no site.

Answer (score 2):

Acho que mais importante que o algoritmo, você precisa entender que a estrutura você escolheu para os seus dados não é adequada. Vou tentar fazer uma comparação aqui pra ver se fica claro como seria melhor:

Você quer guardar informação de várias pessoas, para isso você fez um dicionário que contém listas com as informações:

```
pessoas = {
    "nomes": ["Fulano", "Beltrano", "Sicrano"],
    "idades": [10, 20, 30],
}
```

Se você fosse representar isso fisicamente, você teria um livro que contém apenas o nome de uma pessoa por página e outro livro com apenas as idades nas páginas. Assim para saber a idade de "Beltrano", você teria que abrir o livro de nomes, achar a página em que o nome está e procurar a mesma página no livro de idades.

Como você pode perceber isso não é prático. Uma estrutura mais correta seria ter todas as informações que você quer de uma pessoa na mesma página. Nesse exemplo seria você criar uma lista de dicionário, ao invés de um dicionário de listas.

Veja a diferença:

```
pessoas = [
    {"nome": "Fulano", "idade": 10},
    {"nome": "Beltrano", "idade": 20},
    {"nome": "Sicrano", "idade": 30},
]
```

Dessa maneira, quando você acessa `pessoas[0]` você está vendo todas as informações daquela pessoa numa "página" só.

---

Para ordenar a lista de dicionários basta passar o parâmetro `key` para a função [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) para "ensinar" a função como pegar o valor pelo qual você quer ordenar.

```
pessoas_ordenado = sorted(pessoas, key=lambda obj: obj["nome"])

for pessoa in pessoas_ordenado:
    print(f"{pessoa['nome']} tem {pessoa['idade']} anos.")
```

Saída:

```
Beltrano tem 20 anos.
Fulano tem 10 anos.
Sicrano tem 30 anos.
```

<sup>[Código rodando no Repl.it](https://replit.com/@fernandosavio/SOPt-509681-6333)</sup>

A função [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) retorna uma nova lista ordenada, se você não precisa guardar essa lista separa você pode usar o método [`list.sort()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) que faz a ordenação *inplace*, ou seja, altera a lista original.

Usando [`list.sort()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) ficaria assim:

```
pessoas.sort(pessoas, key=lambda obj: obj["nome"])

for pessoa in pessoas:
    print(f"{pessoa['nome']} tem {pessoa['idade']} anos.")
```

---

Usei dicionários como exemplo para deixar as informações de pessoas no mesma estrutura, mas poderia ser qualquer outra estrutura como objetos de uma classe `Pessoa`, tuplas, tuplas nomeadas, etc..

Alguns exemplos só pra ficar de referência:

Classes:

```
class Pessoa:
    def __init__(self, nome, idade):
        self.nome = nome
        self.idade = idade

pessoas = [
    Pessoa(nome="Fulano", idade=10),
    Pessoa(nome="Beltrano", idade=20),
    Pessoa(nome="Sicrano", idade=30),
]

pessoas_ordenado = sorted(pessoas, key=lambda obj: obj.nome)

for pessoa in pessoas_ordenado:
    print(f"{pessoa.nome} tem {pessoa.idade} anos.")
```

[Tuplas nomeadas](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple):

```
Pessoa = namedtuple('Pessoa', ['nome', 'idade'])

pessoas = [
    Pessoa(nome="Fulano", idade=10),
    Pessoa(nome="Beltrano", idade=20),
    Pessoa(nome="Sicrano", idade=30),
]

pessoas_ordenado = sorted(pessoas, key=lambda obj: obj.nome)

for pessoa in pessoas_ordenado:
    print(f"{pessoa.nome} tem {pessoa.idade} anos.")
```