# Como faço para deixar em ordem alfabética a lista telefonica que esta separada entre maior e menor de idade?

Tags: python, lista, classificação, dicionário

Preiso fazer uma agenda telefonica contendo nome, telefone e idade, após a captura dos dados, preciso separar elas em maiores e menores de 18 anos e imprimir na tela o resultado com todos os dados cadastrados, estou me batendo para que seja realizada a ordem alfabetica. Poderiam me ajudar?

```
agenda = []
dados = {}
maior = []
menor = []
dados['nome'] = input('Digite o Nome: ')


while dados['nome'] != '':
    dados['idade'] = int(input('Digite a Idade: '))
    dados['telefone'] = int(input('Digite o Telefone: '))
    agenda.append(dados.copy())
    dados['nome'] = str(input('Digite o Nome: '))

print('')
print('Total de Cadastros')
print(f'{"Nome":<15}{"Idade":<15}{"Telefone":<15}')
print('')
for contatos in agenda:
    print(f'{contatos["nome"]:<15}{contatos["idade"]:<15}{contatos["telefone"]:<15}')
    if contatos['idade'] >= 18:
        maior.append(contatos)
    if contatos['idade'] < 18:
        menor.append(contatos)
print('-'*50)
print('Maiores de Idade')
print(f'{"Nome":<15}{"Idade":<15}{"Telefone":<15}')
print('')
for contatoslista in maior:
    dados = dict(sorted(dados.items(), key=lambda chave: chave[0]))
    print(f'{contatoslista["nome"]:<15}{contatoslista["idade"]:<15}{contatoslista["telefone"]:<15}')
print('-'*50)
print('Menores de Idade')
print(f'{"Nome":<15}{"Idade":<15}{"Telefone":<15}')
print('')
for contatoslista in menor:
    print(f'{contatoslista["nome"]:<15}{contatoslista["idade"]:<15}{contatoslista["telefone"]:<15}')
```

Comment: A estrutura que você escolheu para seus dados não é a ideal, [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/509681/6333) eu explico um pouco sobre isso.

Answer (score 2):

A estrutura de dados que você tem atualmente para armazenar os contatos, só conseguirá armazenar um único contato. No primeiro loop while, após preencher o primeiro contato, a segunda iteração do loop vai sobrescrever o contato.

Para resolver isso você pode usar uma lista de dicionários, onde cada dicionário é um contato. No final do while, você adiciona no final da lista.

```
lsita_de_contatos = []

while dados['nome'] != '':

    contato = {}

    contato['idade'] = int(input('Digite a Idade: '))
    contato['telefone'] = int(input('Digite o Telefone: '))
    contato['nome'] = str(input('Digite o Nome: '))

    lista_de_contatos.append(contato)
```

Para ordenar os contatos por ordem alfabética dos nomes, você pode fazer:

```
contatos_por_ordem_alfabetica = sorted(lista_de_contatos, key=lambda k: k['nome'])
```

Onde *lambda* é uma pequena função que serve simplismente para coletar o campo que será usado na comparação de ordenação, que nesse caso, é o campo nome.

Por último, para encontrar os contatos que respeitem uma dada condição, você pode fazer uma compreensão de lista que filtrará a lista de contatos:

```
 maiores_de_idade = [contato for contato in lista_de_contatos if contato['idade'] > 18]
```

Essas dicas já aajudam você a resolver todo o resto do problema. Lembre-se de manter o código e as ideias organizadas, assim você chegará na solução que precisa. Boa sorte, espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Obrigado pela colaboração, estou começando nesse mundo e não tem sido fácil, vou colocar em prática as suas dicas, muito obrigado mesmo

Comment: DIsponha. Seja bem-vindo a comunidade python!